# Removing Rows from array

Tags: arrays, r

Hi I have an array in R    `A<-array(c(1:12), dim=c(6,2))`

For the first 3 rows I want to to keep the rows whose value in the first column is less than 3 and for the last 3 rows i want to keep those rows whose value in the first column is less than 4.

Can anybody help me?

So far ive tried      `A[A[,1]<3,]` . This does take care of the first criteria but i dont know then how to deal with the 2nd.

Comment: Perhaps `A[c(head(A[,1],3) <3, tail(A[,1],3) <4),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` and `|` to construct the subset you want to keep:

```
Arow = 1:nrow(A)
A[ (A[,1] <  3 & Arow <= 3) | 
   (A[,1] <  4 & Arow >  3) ,]
```

You don't have to write it over multiple lines, of course. Here's a slightly shorter version:

```
A[A[,1] < 3 + (Arow > 3),]
```

In arithmetic, the logical vector `Arow > 3` is treated as 0 when false and 1 when true.

Comment: Your method is more general

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
A[c(head(A[,1],3) <3, tail(A[,1],3) <4),]
```

The above method didn't take into consideration for datasets with nrow > 6. Possible option for nrow >6 (though not as elegant as @Frank's)

```
 A1 <- A[c(1:3,(nrow(A)-2):nrow(A)),]
 A1[A1[,1] < rep(c(3,4), each=3),]
```